# loss.backward() -> Missing XLA configuration

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

pytorch を用いて作成したモデルから計算された損失を
伝搬する際に、以下のコードを実行すると
以下のエラーメッセージが表示されて困っています。

```
loss.backward()
```

順伝搬の計算は問題なく実行できます。

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  tensorflow/compiler/xla/xla_client/computation_client.cc:280 : Missing XLA configuration
Aborted
```

- pytorch(1.12.0+cu102)
- torchvision(0.13.0+cu102) <- ターゲットのモデルは torchvision.models からインストールできる CNN モデルを含んでいます
- google-compute-engine
- GPU(NVIDIA Tesla T4 x 1, 11.6) <- GPU(11.2)がインストールされている環境では動いていたコードなのですが、現在の環境では動かないです・・・ / 現在の環境では、GPU を利用せず、CPU で動かしても同じエラーが出ます
- TPU はインストールされていません(TPU を使いたいわけではなく、GPUで計算させたいです)

ローカルでは動いているコードで、上述した通り他の GPU 環境でも動いていました。環境がアップデートされたタイミングで動かなくなりました。

助けてください・・・

Answer (score 0):

以下のコマンドで解決しました。

```
$ pip uninstall torch_xla
```

pytorch-ignite と torch_xla の問題であったようです。